# Run a function as multiple jobs at the same time?

Tags: powershell

**Short Version:**
How do I call this function as a job in powershell, is that possible?

**Longer Version:**
I'm trying to speed up getting logs from multiple servers and would like to invoke this function as a job and divide the wait time by the number of servers (basically). I have found that asking for specific date ranges with get-eventlog is slower than just getting a whole bunch of events so the following function just says "give me the latest X, I'll figure out which ones I want to keep". Since I am calling this against multiple servers, I'd like to start numerous jobs and just return the data as they come in. I'm looking for how to launch this as a job and how to return the data. Thoughts?  I have some experience with jobs in shell scripts and running scripts as jobs in powershell if that helps. Is my only recourse to create a separate script and call that? Thoughts? Thanks in advance. MQ

```
Function Get-EventLogData() {
    param ($Server, $LogName, $RawSampleSize, $Hours)
    $Log = @()
    Try {
        # -- Event Log capture --
        $LogCapture = Get-EventLog -LogName $LogName -Newest $RawSampleSize -ComputerName $Server
        If ($Hours) {
            $StartTime = (Get-Date).AddHours($Hours)
            foreach ($Entry in $LogCapture) {
                if ($Entry.TimeGenerated -ge $StartTime) {
                    $Log += $Entry
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            foreach ($Entry in $LogCapture) {
                $Log += $Entry
            }
        }
    } 
    Catch {
        Write-Host ("Something went wrong with [" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand + "] for " + $Server + " ..") -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    return $Log
}
```

Comment: In my experience `Invoke-Command { Get-EventLog..... } -ComputerName "server"` is faster than `Get-EventLog -ComputerName "server"`, is that something available to you ?

Comment: Also `Get-EventLog` is a bit old, you might wanna use `Get-WinEvent`

Comment: I wrote someting similar to retrieve security logs from Domain Controllers. You can use `Start-Job` to start all the searches concurrently, then write Do..Until loop to check for the jobs finishing. Once they've all finished you can collect and process them. And yes, use `Get-WinEvent` if you can

Comment: I agree with Santiago with sending the request to the remote PC to process instead of doing it on yours. You can also include `-AsJob` to run `Invoke-command -cn nasdf { .. } `.

Comment: Yup, in addition `Invoke-Command` accepts an array of `ComputerName` or a `PSSession` which can also be an array of computers and will execute the invocation on all of them at the same time. Remote servers should take the leverage of your task :) let them do the work!

Comment: @Scepticalist  Thanks I have done start-job, I wasn't sure if I could use that with a function of my own making.